# Simplicial homology - what does it mean to differ by an even permutation?

Tags: algebraic-topology

I read that two orderings of a simplex are equivalent if they differ by an even permutation. May I wonder what is the exact definition of differing by an even permutation?

For example, if my simplex is generated by points $v_0,\cdots, v_3$, and my first ordering is $v_1, v_0, v_2, v_3$ and my second one is $v_0,v_1,v_3,v_2$, do they differ by an even permutation?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have made *two* transpositions; you swapped $v_1$ with its neighbour, $v_0$, and then you swapped $v_3$ with its neighbour $v_2$. Since $2$ is an even number, that's an even permutation.

More formally there is a homomorphism $\sigma:S_n\to\{\pm1\}$ which maps transpositions to $-1$. We say a permutation $\tau$ is even iff. $\sigma(\tau)=+1$.

Comment: Thank you! @FShrike